# How to create separate ribbon for outlook add-in so that it is placed in the main tabs in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, ribbonx

**Is it possible to create/display add-in in separate ribbon at the top bar in outlook? **
I tried by using "PrimaryCommandSurface" , "ContosoRibbonTab" but it gave the "Invalid xsi:type" error.

Can you please help in updating the valid manifest.xml for outlook.

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
.
<!-- Existing manifest content -->
.
 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="CustomTabId">
              <Group id="CustomGroupId" label="Custom Group">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="CustomButtonId">
                  <Label resid="buttonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="buttonLabel" />
                    <Description resid="buttonDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>customButtonAction</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="tabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

My Enviornment-Details: - (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by main tabs( if possible attach an image).  Are you trying this on Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm trying it on windows.
By main tabs I mean to say that on the top bar where "File", "Message", "Help" etc, ribbons are displayed. So I need to display seperate ribbon for my add-in ribbon at top bar.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Soham. These 2 tutorials explain about how to create an add-in - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial . Since, this manifest is incomplete, we are unable to find the problem. Could you see if the examples in these tutorials help you? They have screenshots of where the add-in gets added. Is this where you want it?

Comment: That is not supported currently.

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported currently. You need to develop COM/VSTO add-ins if you want to customize built-in ribbon tabs in Outlook. Not all features of the Ribbon UI (Fluent UI) customizations are available to web add-ins.

The add-in commands 1.3 requirement set introduces manifest markup that enables an add-in to customize the placement of a custom tab on the Office ribbon and to insert built-in Office ribbon controls into custom control groups. See [Add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#types-of-add-in-commands) for getting started with ribbon customizations in Office add-ins.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.